# Full-Featured broadcast-level open source Video Editors?

Tags: broadcasting

I need edit SxS XDCAM footage for news, is there a full-Featured  broadcast-level open source video editor?

At last need unlinking different audio channels in timeline.

Comment: This is really already covered by the existing question on open source video editors.  A quick look at the listed options will show which ones are suitable for broadcast engineering.  Lightworks is probably the most promising.

Comment: link to duplicate?